# why my first created row in database have id null1

Tags: java, android

my problem is, when I put something in my text fields and save that to database, the ID of that row is null1
instead of 1
here is my code for creating database and putting data in database :

```
    private HelperDb myHelper;
    private final Context myContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
    private static class HelperDb extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public HelperDb(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        KEY_NAME + " STRING, " +
        KEY_TEKST + " TEXT, " +
        KEY_DATUM + " STRING, " +
        KEY_VREME + " STRING);"
                );


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        this.onCreate(db);

    }

}

public Baza(Context c){
    myContext = c;
}

public Baza open() throws SQLException {
    myHelper = new HelperDb(myContext);
    myDatabase = myHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    myHelper.close();
}

// this is how I put data in database
public long unesiPodatkeBaza(String ime, String napisaniTekst, String uneseniDatum, String unesenoVreme) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, ime);
    cv.put(KEY_TEKST, napisaniTekst);
    cv.put(KEY_DATUM, uneseniDatum);
    cv.put(KEY_VREME, unesenoVreme);

    return myDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}
```

later that make problem for application.

This is how I collect data from database:

```
public String[] getData() {

    String[] kolone = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_TEKST, KEY_DATUM, KEY_VREME};

    Cursor c = myDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, kolone, null, null, null, null, null);

    iRed = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    iIme = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    iTekst = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TEKST);
    iDatum = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATUM);
    iVreme = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_VREME);

    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iRed) + " " + c.getString(iIme) + " " + c.getString(iTekst) + " " + c.getString(iDatum) + " " + c.getString(iVreme) + "\n";
    }

    return result.split("\n");
}
```

and this is what I'm doing with data:

```
public class SQLPregled extends Activity{

    public String[] data;
    private ListView lv;
    private int idSend;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pregledbaze);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvListaBaza);

        final Baza izlistavanje = new Baza(this);
        izlistavanje.open();
        data = izlistavanje.getData();
        izlistavanje.close();


        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data));

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

                String tmplv = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                String[] odvojeni = tmplv.split(" ");

                idSend = Integer.parseInt(odvojeni[0]);

                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(SQLPregled.this);
                adb.setTitle("Dali zelite da obrisete izabranu poruku?");
                adb.setMessage("Id je : " + odvojeni[0]);
                adb.setPositiveButton("Obrisi", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        izlistavanje.open();
                        izlistavanje.deleteData(idSend); 
                        izlistavanje.close();
                        onCreate(null); 

                    }
                }); 

                adb.setNegativeButton("Odustani", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.cancel(); 
                    }
                });

                adb.show(); 
            }

        }); 

    } // onCreate

}
```

Comment: A helpful read would be: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it certainly can not have an ID of "null1" as the table definition has the ID defined as an INTEGER, so you would get errors when trying to set that value and the db would not store it that way.

it's more likely that when you're reading / displaying it, you're appending it to a null value so null + 1 = "null1" though some sort of string cast hocus pocus.  Can you show us how you're getting and displaying the id field?  Why do you think it's "null1"?

Comment: SQLite uses dynamic typing, see: [FAQ: SQLite lets me insert a string into a database column of type integer!](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q3).

Comment: It does sound like a printing issue - it could be a `System.out.print` statement from anywhere else in the program (as long as it executes before)

Comment: in getData(), is result initialized to "" or is it null to start with?

Comment: I didn't initialized result, and that was the problem, when I put empty string result=""; that solve problem.
thank you elijah.